# Schema.org markup for product length (instead of depth)

Tags: schema.org

On the Schema.org documentation for [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) they list `height` and `width` properties, but they do not list *length*.

They do however have depth:

> `depth`:
>   `QuantitativeValue` or `Distance`:
>   The depth of the item.

So if I want to mark up the length of my products, is it valid to use the `depth` property?

I'm hesitant as depth has a different meaning to length, but there is no length property.

Comment: Yeah. I wondered about this too! Seems incomplete to me. Especially for products such as flag poles, lumber, mattresses, string, extension chords, etc.

Comment: Older issue without any answers yet: [Product dimensions should be length x width x height](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/528)